# I want to hide a menu item to registered users

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, access

I want to hide a menu item to registered users, but when I use "Guest" access that item disappears! so no one can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that in User->Manage->Options that the value of the field **Guest User Group** is set to **Guest**.

Comment: it was public, I've changed it to guest and it worked....thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question, but I stumbled across this asking the same question as above. I was running into the same page display issue with the "Guest" access permission. While the answer above was helpful, it did not accomplish the outcome I was looking for, right now I'm currently working on Joomla ‎(3.9.19). I found that I didn't need to change the page permissions at all, and if you go to "Menu>Main Menu>(Select the page you wish to hide)>Link Type>Display in Menu Switch to No." It will hide the page from a registered user's menu.

I'm not sure if this option was available at the time of the question was asked. But it is now, and I was able to accomplish the exact outcome I was looking for, which was to hide a menu item from a "Registered" user's menu while still allowing a "Registered" user to access the page via a dashboard button I created. Previously, when I had changed the user permission to, "Guest" the "Registered" user was getting a 403 error when clicking on the button I created that linked to the page I was hiding in the "Registered" user's menu.
[image: Display in Menu Switch reference]

Answer (score 0):

This its the same answer from @Piero Marsilio, but with visual tutorial.

4 - Check if "Guest User Groupr" is set to "Guest".
Thanks Pierro!

[image]